# If a function is continuously differentiable at a point are it's anti-derivative also continuous differentiable at that point

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If a function is continuously differentiable at a point are it's anti-derivative also continuous differentiable at that point?

I've been considering the following problem,

$$ \lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \int_0^{t} f(s, g(s)) ds = 0$$

Now the question is: What conditions are required for the above equation to hold?

I would like say that $f$ must be continuously differentiable so that it's anti-derivative $F$ is also. Then, $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} F(t, g(t)) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0^-} F(t, g(t)) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} F(t, g(t)) = F(0, g(0))$ and hence $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \int_0^{t} f(s, g(s)) ds = \big[\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} F(t, g(t)) \big] - F(0, g(0)) = 0$.

$\textbf{To clarify:}$

I would like to know if my proof is correct and if a continuously differentiable function also has continuously differentiable anti-derivatives?

Comment: The anti-derivative of any continuous function, whether it is even differentiable or not, is continuously differentiable simply by the "fundamental theorem of Calculus"!  The derivative of the anti-derivative **is** that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anti-derivative has extra level of smoothness. If $f$ is a $C^{k}$ function then an anti-derivative of $f$ is a $C^{k+1}$ function. So the answer is YES.

Comment: Is my proof also correct?

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that the assumptions of continuity of $f$ is sufficient but not necessary. Instead we ask simply that $f$ stays bounded below
$$
f(s, g(s)) \geq m > -\infty \quad \forall s \tag{1}\label{b1}
$$ 
and bounded above 
$$
f(s, g(s)) \leq M < \infty \quad \forall s. \tag{2}\label{b2}
$$
Then 
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^t \min_{t'} f(t', g(t')) dt &\leq \int_0^t f(s, g(s))ds \leq \int_0^t \max_{t'} f(t', g(t')) \\
t \min_{t'} f(t', g(t')) &\leq \int_0^t f(s, g(s))ds \leq t \max_{t'} f(t', g(t')).
\end{align}
$$
Using the bounds \eqref{b1}, \eqref{b2} then
$$
t\, m \leq \int_0^t f(s, g(s))ds \leq t\, M
$$
Now we let $t \rightarrow 0^+$,
$$ 
0 \leq \underset{t \rightarrow 0^+}{\lim} \int_0^t f(s, g(s))ds \leq 0
$$
which can only be true if 
$$
\underset{t \rightarrow 0^+}{\lim} \int_0^t f(s, g(s))ds = 0.
$$